# How can I specify just to install one thing with bower?

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

Given the following:

```
{
  "name": "user_staging1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0"
  }
}

{
  "name": "user_staging2",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-loading-bar": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Then how can I ask bower to just install user_staging1 ?

Also can someone tell me what is the purpose of the resolutions area?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to install just one package, you use `bower install package_name` (you can add `--save` parameter if you want to save this dependency to your own `bower.json` file).

Resolutions area helps resolve dependency version conflicts. For example, if `angular-ui-router` depends on `angular version 1.4.0` while `angular-loading-bar` depends on `angular version 1.3.0` when you run `bower install` you will get a message like the following:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
1) angular 1.3.0 which is required by angular-loading-bar
2) angular 1.4.0 which is required by angular-ui-router
```

and you will have to choose either 1 or 2. In order to persist this choice  and prevent bower from asking you all the time the above question, you can add your choice to resolutions area.